# SELECT * FROM table, replace FK's with their name

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have 2 tables, product has a primary key and a name, price has a pk, a `fk(pk of product)` and price. now I have to `select * from price`, but need to show the product name instead of the fk. how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT pd.name, pc.price
    FROM product AS pd
        INNER JOIN price AS pc
            ON pd.id = pc.productid
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it that way:

```
Select p.*, pr.Name from price as p
join product as pr on p.productid = pr.Id
```